# Status: Checked out by [USERNAME]

Tags: check-out

Can anyone enlighten me on what this means?

Never seen it before in 3 years - all of the sudden I get this message on our "top" team-site.

How did it happend?
What does it do and how do I prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 1):

John Scnabel user has checked-out the page for editing, you can go to Page library (if Publishing pages) or Site Pages library to discard check-out or check-in the page.

Please have a look at following article for more details:
[Check out, check in, or discard changes to files in a site library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-out-check-in-or-discard-changes-to-files-in-a-site-library-e3146e32-978c-4a35-8d24-1e7e2e640b80)

Answer (score 1):

When someone is making modifications to a publishing page, but the changes are not published (not saved) yet - then this message will appear.

This will go away when the page is checked in and published.